# Aligning an SVG element with left hand side of page

Tags: html, css, svg

I've started tooling around with SVG as it looks really promising.

I can't quite understand how to align the elements, however. I'm currently trying to make a sample page with a large title that sticks to the left-hand side of the webpage and is vertically centered.

I've set something up, but when the width of the page changes, the SVG moves into the left-hand side of the page instead of just staying there (image below).

[image: A screenshot of the issue]
[image]

I'd like to know how I can fix this, plus why exactly SVG does this. I've set the viewbox and the text element's X value to `x="0"` which I'd imagine would fix it. I don't understand a lot about SVG so forgive me for novice mistakes.

Here's my code in an MCVE.

```
<html>
    <header>
        <style>
        /* Visual styling, adds color, font, etc. ----------- */
        body{
          background-color: #121212;
          font-family: "Segoe UI";
        }
        /* Actual structured styling, grid, margin, etc. -------- */
        svg{
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }
        #mainTitle{
          font-weight: 200;
          font-size: 20px;
          letter-spacing: 2px;
          fill: #d8d8d8;
        }
        </style>
    </header>
    <body>
        <svg viewbox = "0 0 200 200">
            <text x = "0" y = "100" id="mainTitle" text-anchor="middle"> Sample Text </text>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you know of any good learning resources (not W3) for SVG feel free to drop a link too.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aligning the text to the center and setting x=0 means that the center of the text will align with the left side of the screen, and half of it will be cut off.

Try this instead:

```
<text x = "50%" y = "20" id="mainTitle" text-anchor="middle"> Sample Text </text>
```

Notice that I have used x="50%" and text-anchor="middle".  This can be seen as a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/bov53wz8/4/.  Note I also set y="20" to make the title appear closer to the top, but you can change that as you like.

A good tutorial on a site I usually like to go to is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial
Also, a good reference when using SVG for web design: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a ton, seems so obvious to me now.